# document.getElementById("id") not getting the element on first click of the mat-expansion-panel-header?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I  have an Angular mat-expansion-panel in that I have a div, but while trying to access the div in my typescript on click of that mat Expansion Panel I am getting that div with checkboxes but that checkboxes are not checked or unchecked and if I give the call in header section the div is getting as null in first click and in second click I am getting the div with checkboxes and checkboxes are working fine don't know what is happening. Any ideas?? this is my code

HTML code:

```
     <mat-expansion-panel
         (click)="this.LoadAllLayers(); this.isLayerPanelExpanded=!this.isLayerPanelExpanded;">
       <mat-expansion-panel-header id="layer-switcher-title">
         <mat-panel-title>
           <b>Layers</b>
         </mat-panel-title>
       </mat-expansion-panel-header>
       <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
         <div #layerDiv id="layerPanel"></div>
       </ng-template>
     </mat-expansion-panel>
```

typeScript code:

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
     if(this.isLayerPanelExpanded) {
      this.LoadAllLayers();
     }
   }


   LoadAllLayers() {
     this.map = this.mapService.getMap();
     layerdivElement: HTMLElement | null = this.layerDiv.nativeElement;
     const legenddoc = document.getElementById('layerPanel');
     this.layerdivElement=document.getElementById('layerPanel');
     while (this.layerdivElement!.firstChild) {
        this.layerdivElement!.removeChild(this.layerdivElement!.lastChild!);
     }

     const allgrpLayer = this.map.getLayers().getArray();
     for (let t = 0; t < allgrpLayer.length; t++) {
       const grpLayer = allgrpLayer[t].getLayersArray();
       if (grpLayer.length > 0) {
       for (let j = 0; j < grpLayer.length; j++) {
         const layer = grpLayer[j];
         if (layer.getSource() instanceof ImageWMS) {
           const layerContainer = document.createElement("div");
           layerContainer.className = "layer-container"; 
           const layerCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
           layerCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
           layerCheckbox.checked = layer.getVisible(); 
           layerCheckbox.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
             const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
             layer.setVisible(target.checked);
           });
           const layerLabel = document.createElement("label");
           layerLabel.textContent = layer.getClassName();
           layerLabel.style.fontWeight = '800';
           layerContainer.appendChild(layerCheckbox);
           layerContainer.appendChild(layerLabel);
           this.layerdivElement!.appendChild(layerContainer);
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

I tried it for a day and nothing worked .Any Ideas why its happening like this? Many thanks in advance

Comment: 1) do not access DOM in your TS (neither use jQuery, nor getElementById). 2) you have to wait for the `AfterViewInit()` hook if you want to access the HTML.

Comment: to elaborate, you should use `@ViewChild('layerPanel', {static: false}) layerPanel;` to access your element in your typescript.